# I have a 9V battery, but I only need to output 4.5V from it. How do I accomplish this?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

This is the circuit I have so far: [Falstad Voltage Divider Circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+53+5+43%0Aw+48+352+96+352+0%0Ar+96+352+96+224+0+10000000%0Aa+256+208+400+208+0+15+-15+1000000+-0.000662125604726191+-0.0007419317565048359%0Aw+256+224+96+224+0%0A174+176+128+208+192+0+10000+0.1337+Resistance%0Aw+256+192+256+160+0%0Aw+208+160+256+160+0%0Aw+176+128+176+112+0%0Aw+96+112+176+112+0%0Aw+96+352+176+352+0%0Aw+176+192+176+352+0%0A162+400+112+400+208+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+304+112+400+112+0+680%0Aw+304+112+176+112+0%0Aw+-32+352+48+352+0%0Ad+96+224+96+112+1+0.805904783%0Av+-32+144+-32+80+0+0+40+9+0+0+0.5%0Ar+32+48+32+96+0+1000%0Ar+32+112+32+160+0+1000%0Aw+32+160+-32+160+0%0Aw+-32+144+-32+160+0%0Aw+-32+80+-32+48+0%0Aw+-32+48+32+48+0%0Aw+32+96+32+112+0%0Aw+96+112+32+112+0%0Aw+-32+352+-32+160+0%0A)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPrLBC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, I tried using a simple voltage divider, but this interferes with the other resistors in the circuit and does not give me the desired voltage. I want to know if there is a way to turn a 9V source into a 4.5V source WITHOUT changing anything in the circuit as it is.

Comment: get a DC to DC converter from an online seller...

Comment: You probably want a rail splitter circuit (or IC) that can support the currents involved.

Comment: @jonk You mean like this? https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=y9x79d

Comment: @User No. I didn't mean that. No sink/source compliance to speak of. But you've set your circuit up in Falstad with \$\pm 15\:\text{V}\$ to the opamp. So I honestly don't know where the \$9\:\text{V}\$ is coming from in the first place. Are you planning to use \$9\:\text{V}\$ as the power supply for the opamp rails?

Comment: Use some type of voltage regulator.

Comment: You need to explain your end goal. Is the opamp your problem, or solution. To drive just the diode, something simpler would work.

Comment: Why, where and to what, do you need 4.5 V?  Also, how precise does the voltage need to be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so this is what I have come up with so far. I used an inverting amplifier. I think this accomplishes my goal unless I am missing something: [Updated circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+53+5+43%0Aw+368+432+416+432+0%0Ar+416+432+416+304+0+10000000%0Aa+576+288+720+288+0+15+-15+1000000+3.8982915256271156+1.7143528192953283%0Aw+576+304+416+304+0%0A174+496+208+528+272+0+10000+0.1337+Resistance%0Aw+576+272+576+240+0%0Aw+528+240+576+240+0%0Aw+496+208+496+192+0%0Aw+416+192+496+192+0%0Aw+416+432+496+432+0%0Aw+496+272+496+432+0%0A162+720+192+720+288+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+624+192+720+192+0+680%0Aw+624+192+496+192+0%0Ad+416+304+416+192+1+0.805904783%0Aw+64+256+224+256+0%0Ag+64+256+64+304+0%0Aa+224+192+352+192+0+15+-15+1000000+-0.00004499932501012485+0%0Aw+224+208+224+256+0%0Aw+352+96+352+192+0%0Aw+224+96+224+176+0%0Aw+224+176+176+176+0%0Ar+224+96+352+96+0+500%0Ar+64+176+176+176+0+1000%0Av+64+176+64+256+0+0+40+9+0+0+0.5%0Aw+288+432+224+432+0%0Aw+224+256+224+432+0%0Aw+368+192+416+192+0%0Aw+368+192+352+192+0%0Aw+368+432+288+432+0%0A)

Comment: Where's the magic battery supplying the negative voltage to the first opamp? Always keep in mind, an opamp can only supply output voltages within the range of its power rails. The output of your first buffer has to reach \$-0.5 U_{supply}\$

Comment: Besides the fact that your circuit won't work without additional batteries, keep in mind that this Q&A-site depends on persistence of information. So it is preferred to use the built in schematic feature. Nevertheless I like that schematic display app you used.

Comment: Please post updates into your question unless you are actually posing an answer. Answers float up and down depending on votes or user sort preferences so you can't use this site as a discussion forum as post sequence can't be guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

No, not with that design. Buy an LM7805 voltage regulator (they are cheap). Add bypass capacitors as required. Add a 1N5822 diode on the output with a tiny minimum load. The final voltage will be close to 4.5 volts, but not exact.

To get 4.500 volts to within 1% or better you will need a more complex circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fniHrT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No . Your design is flawed with no buffer for the split rail and loading the 1k's with an LED.

Comment: A bit short what.